# egmap Google Maps Yii not saving data to database

Tags: google-maps, yii, yii-extensions

I am using egmaps extensions with Yii application it is a very brilliant application. how ever I am having trouble populating database. my database table hotel has two attributes for long and lat. I am not expert in AJAX but i think that ajax is calling controler method. At present I donot have anything in controler method because I donot know what data will come and how?

my code so far is BUT I THINK THIS AJAX IS NOT CALLING THE CONTROLLER SaveCoordinates action

```
 $gMap->zoom = 6;
            $mapTypeControlOptions = array(
              'position' => EGMapControlPosition::RIGHT_TOP,
              'style' => EGMap::MAPTYPECONTROL_STYLE_HORIZONTAL_BAR
            );

            $gMap->mapTypeId = EGMap::TYPE_ROADMAP;
            $gMap->mapTypeControlOptions = $mapTypeControlOptions;

            // Preparing InfoWindow with information about our marker.
            $info_window_a = new EGMapInfoWindow("<div class='gmaps-label' style='color: #000;'>Hi! I'm your marker!</div>");

            // Setting up an icon for marker.
            $icon = new EGMapMarkerImage("http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/car.png");

            $icon->setSize(32, 37);
            $icon->setAnchor(16, 16.5);
            $icon->setOrigin(0, 0);

            // Saving coordinates after user dragged our marker.
            $dragevent = new EGMapEvent('dragend', 'function (event) { $.ajax({
                                                        type:"POST",
                                                        url:"'.$this->createUrl('hotel/savecoords').'/'.$model->id.'",
                                                        data:({lat: event.latLng.lat(), lng: event.latLng.lng()}),

                                                        cache:false,
                                                    });}', false, EGMapEvent::TYPE_EVENT_DEFAULT);
if($model->long)
{
            // If we have already created marker - show it
                $marker = new EGMapMarker($model->lat, $model->long, array('title' => Yii::t('catalog', $model->name),
                        'icon'=>$icon, 'draggable'=>true), 'marker', array('dragevent'=>$dragevent));
                $marker->addHtmlInfoWindow($info_window_a);
                $gMap->addMarker($marker);
                $gMap->setCenter($model->lat, $model->long);
                $gMap->zoom = 16;
}
else
{
                // Setting up new event for user click on map, so marker will be created on place and respectful event added.
                $gMap->addEvent(new EGMapEvent('click',
                        'function (event) {var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: event.latLng, map: '.$gMap->getJsName().
                        ', draggable: true, icon: '.$icon->toJs().'}); '.$gMap->getJsName().
                        '.setCenter(event.latLng); var dragevent = '.$dragevent->toJs('marker').
                        '; $.ajax({'.
                          '"type":"POST",'.
                          '"url":"'.$this->createUrl('hotel/savecoords')."/".$model->id.'",'.
                          '"data":({"lat": event.latLng.lat(), "lng": event.latLng.lng()}),'.
                          '"cache":false,'.
                        '}); }', false, EGMapEvent::TYPE_EVENT_DEFAULT_ONCE));
}
            $gMap->renderMap(array(), Yii::app()->language);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved in case other may get stuck I solved it by changing `POST` to `GET` and URL Line

```
url:"'.$this->createUrl('hotel/savecoords').'/'.$model->id.'", '
```

to

```
url':'".$this->createUrl('hotel/savecoords', array('id'=>$model->id))."',`
```

and controller code is

```
 public function actionSaveCoords($id)
        {
            $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
                // 
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
            if(isset ($_GET['lat']))
                $model->lat = $_GET['lat'];
            if(isset ($_GET['lat']))
                $model->long = $_GET['lng'];
            if($model->save())
                {
                    echo 'Thank you for registring your place with '.Yii::app()->name;  
                }
                $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I used POST, and it works. Maybe in your Model's rules params are not specified?